# CPLEX gap progress with time in C#

Tags: c#, cplex

I have an MILP model that takes very long time to get optimal solutions. I've coded MILP model in C# and call CPLEX to run the model. I would like to see the progress of the gap in time. How could I get this information?

Answer (score 1):

Do it with a cplex callback. I think it would be a mipinfo callback from memory. It would most likely be called many times per second so I normally record the previous time that I wrote information, and only write an update after 1 or 5 or 10 seconds for example. Normally write to a text file in CSV format so that it is easy to use with eg Excel.

Comment: there is an option for gap value in cplex as cplex.GetMIPRelativeGap(), but it only keeps the final gap value. I could not find how to save gap values progressively in time.